# Content in UIWebView on iOS 3.1.3 appears zoomed on but on iOS 4.3 appears fine

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiwebview

I am running into a difference in UIWebView behaviour on two different devices I am testing.  First here is the listing of devices I am testing with...

**Device #1** -> iPod 2G / iOS 3.1.3

**Device #2** -> iPhone 4 / iOS 4.3

I have the same HTML content being loaded on both devices but when it's loaded on the iPod the content appears zoomed in.  On the iPhone the content appears correctly.  From what I know I think this may have to do with retina display and perhaps the iPhone can natively accept content at a larger resolution but I have nothing confirmed at the moment.  Wondering if anyone has encountered this type of behaviour before.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the size of your HTML content? 640x960?
Did you use `scalesPageToFit`?

Answer (score 1):

You should set scalesPageToFit of your UIWebView to YES and insert this meta tag in your html header:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;' />
```

There are plenty of parameters for CONTENT, some of them are:

```
maximum-scale=3.0; //Maximum zoom allowed 0 to 10.0. default is 1.6
minimum-scale=0.5; //Minimum zoom allowed 0 to 10.0. default is 0.25
user-scalable=1; //YES/NO
width=device-width; //default if not set is 980px 
initial-scale=1.0; //Initial zoom. 0 to 10.0. 1.0 would be 100%
```

This way your UIWebView should display your web the way you want.
Hope this helps!