# iOS webview CSS hacks

Tags: ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview

I am loading a webview in iOS app, which will print a screen. When loading in webview it is printing in 2 pages and when we are running in browser it is working perfectly fine by printing in one page.

Is there some css @media that can effect only iOS webview html?

Comment: Maybe you find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6191517/3623608). Idk if its directly connected to your question.

Comment: @Tommy I will check and update it, if it works

Comment: Tommy I checked it and it didn't work. My problem is with print coming in 3 pages. I need to remove padding and margin that is coming extra in iOS webview. So if their is any @media Target that I can apply those css for only iOS webview.  I am also trying if I can load webview using chrome so that my issue may be fixed? Can we load chrome useagent for webview?